# Perform assembly/alignment of two objects

Tags: mesh

Firstly, I am new to blender and have never used it until now, I search for something similar but couldn't be able to find. For my thesis, I am working with .STL files and I have a question about whether it is possible to make an assembly process between two objects using the mesh vertex's. What I want to do is place the selected vertices (image 1) coincident and perform the assembly as I make here (image 2).

image 1: [image]

image 2:[image]

I wrote a script in python to perform that "assembly" but im checking if there is a software capable of do that because it is more user-friendly and there is a thing that blender does that I need: when I move the object to any place in space, when I export that file, he puts new coordinates . So what I need is to guarantee that I can perform the correct alignment of the two objects in blender and that's ok!

Thank's for the attention

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to use vertex snapping and the origin point.

1. Make sure your sphere is oriented correctly.
2. Enable *Vertex snapping > Median*
3. Check *Only origins* and snap your *origin point* to the top vertex. Then uncheck.
4. Select your sphere and snap it to the other object's top vertex

*Snap the origin point to the top vertex*
[image]

*Snap the sphere to the other object's top vertex*
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for my thesis example! But I take the moment to ask something more: now imagine a case in which I want to make contact with two objects using 2 vertices. is it possible to "match" a vertex first and fix objects at that point and then make the other coincide? or instead of coinciding with two vertices, fix 1 vertex and then rotate one object over that fixed vertex. What im asking is operations likely assembly process in a CAD software but it really helps me if could be possible with meshes

Comment: Hello :). That is certainly possible, but please ask it as a new question to keep this site organized. You may also find similar threads on this site, I'm sure it was asked before.

Comment: In the meantime, please mark the answer as accepted **✓**, for others with a similar question :).